# Display user selection in <select> using Angular 7 template driven form

Tags: angular, angular-forms, two-way-binding

I have the array `possibleAnswers[]`, containing possible options for the select and one element of the array `chosenFields[]`, containing the one option i need to display as selected.

The possible answers and the selected one are both coming from different endpoints. How do I achieve the data-binding?

I tried using both the `[comparedWith]`, `[selected]`, `[ngValue]` and `[value]` tag but it didn't work.

```
 <select class="form-control" id="possibleAnswersOfField{{j}}" name="selectForQuestion{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="answers[i].chosenFields[j]">
     <option *ngFor="let answer of question.possibleAnswers" [selected]="answer == answers[i].chosenFields[j]">{{answer}}</option>
 </select>
```

Angular is always selecting the last element of `possibleAnswers` as the selected option, which is weird because as you can see in the screenshots below the last element "blau" has no selection tag.

[image: resulting html]

This is the form:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

[selected] is the correct way to achieve this, you need to pass true if the value is the one you want to select.

Or if you need to see if the value matches the chosenFields value, it would look something like this.

```
 <option *ngFor="let answer of question.possibleAnswers" [selected]="answer == chosenFields[0]">
         {{answer}}
     </option>
```

This way [selected] will evaluate to true is the two values match.

Comment: I should mention here that you need to have the selected answer from chosenFields[] in the possibleAnswers[], or you will never evaluate selected to true. So you will have to add it if it is not there already.

Comment: I added the [selected] tag and also uploaded a screenshot of the resulting html. The correct selection would be "grün" but it's not being selected. Even though it correctly appears in the "ng-reflect-model" tag.